# How do i use a c# windows forms app as a server for a single client on same windows desktop pc?

Tags: .net, winforms, server, com, grpc

I have a c# (.NET 7) windows forms application. I would like to expose some functionalities for a 3rt client program, which could be installed on same desketop windows pc.

When my app is with .NET48 I used COM technology and it works well.
But now the .NET7 COM can not works because a .NET7 ComVisble dll needs to load .NET7-Windows app. And it failed.
I tryed With gRPC, but i have problems with multithread and invokes to windows Forms controls.

What i am doing wrong? What Is the best technology to do this?

Comment: If you have something with COM that worked with .NET Framework, it should work with .NET 7 (possibly with some modification or a bit of work, but it should work) Please give more details and a small complete reproducible code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example